# Show a text when Product ID

Tags: prestashop

I'm on prestashop 1.7 and I need your help to show a text when product id = 12

this code does not work

```
{if $product.id_product == 10} TEST {/if}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

loop through the product i think you need foreach loop to fetch the matched product.

```
foreach ($product.id_product as $_product_ID) {
{if $_product_ID== 10} 
TEST 
{/if}
}
```